# How to understand these sentences?

Tags: comparative-constructions

> [1] ... Visit the Navy Yard, and behold a marine, **such** a man
>   **as** an American government can make, or **such as** it can make a man with its black arts — a mere shadow and reminiscence of humanity,
>   a man laid out alive and standing, and already, as one may say, buried
>   under arms with funeral accompaniments, though it may be
>
> “Not a drum was heard, not a funeral note, As his corse to the rampart
>   we hurried; Not a soldier discharged his farewell shot O’er the grave
>   where our hero we buried.”
>
> [2] The mass of men serve the state **thus**, not as men mainly, but as
>   machines, with their bodies. They are the standing army, and the
>   militia, jailers, constables, posse comitatus, etc. **In most cases
>   there is no free exercise whatever of the judgment or of the moral
>   sense; but they put themselves on a level with wood and earth and
>   stones;** and wooden men can perhaps be manufactured that will serve the
>   purpose as well.

The quote is from On the Duty of Civil Disobedience by Thoreau, I have several questions:

1. In the first paragraph, if "*Visit the Navy Yard...*" is a imperative sentence, does "**such** a man **as** an American government can make" modify "a marine"? There're two "such ... as ..." but they are asymmetric, what's the structure and how to understand this paragraph?
2. Does "*thus*" in the second paragraph mean "therefore" or "in this way, in the way that"?
3. > In most cases there is no free exercise whatever of the judgment or of the moral sense; but they put themselves on a level with wood and earth and stones;

   Does it mean "the state doesn't allow them to exert free exercise of ..." OR "they don't exert free exercise in the state"? How can I determine the subject in a general way?

   What's the meaning of "but" here? Can I associate it with "no"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The two comparative constructions are parallel (with a touch of anaphora and ellipsis ) and conjoined by *or*; the conjunction stands in [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) to the noun phrase *a marine* as a supplement (an entity lying outside the syntax of the clause) defining what *a marine* is:

   ```
   a marine, such  a man   as an American government can make, 
             or 
             such [a man] as            it           can make [into] a man with its black arts
   ```

   Paraphrase: ... a marine is the sort of man which an American government can make or make into a man ...
2. *Thus* means both *in consequence* and *in this manner*
3. In the first clause the subject is the dummy pronoun *there*. Thoreau thus refrains from specifying precisely where it is that judgment and the moral sense are not exercised, but we may infer with some confidence that it is among these men, or in the service which they perform. Their conscious agency is implied in the second-clause statement that the marines "**put themselves** on a level with wood, &c": the marines are the subject, and we are I think constrained to infer that they freely forego their own freedom. But since the absence of freewill likewise implies an absence of agency, the marines abrogate their agentive humanity and become effectively equivalent to the wooden men by which they may be readily replaced.

   But all this inference is LitCrit and not really on topic here.

Comment: Is it right "a mere shadow and reminiscence of humanity" belongs to the former sentence and "a man laid out ..." forms a new sentence? What can "but" in the second paragraph be placed with? Can I understand that it isn't an adversative conjunction here and isn't associated with "no" in the first clause?

Comment: And I was so looking forward to a bit of naughty LitCrit! I could see Swedenborg looming like a wraith, roused from his slumber by the mention of _freewill..._